# Add own button in safari 3,4 with bundle file

Tags: objective-c, macos, safari-extension

I try to create and add button in toolbar of safari version 3,4 by file bundle in Mac ( use XCode )

- When I restart browser and open it again . It's work, but it make
  default toolbar changed.
- But if I just close safari (not quit) or create new window safari or create new tab
  my button is disappear.

I trying use extension but it just work in safari 5 or later.
I use file .nib and add button with 3 method delegate of NSToolbar:

- (NSToolbarItem *)toolbar:(NSToolbar *)toolbar
   itemForItemIdentifier:(NSString *)itemIdentifier
  willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:(BOOL)flag
- (NSArray *)toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar*)toolbar
- (NSArray *)toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers:(NSToolbar*)toolbar

Please help me...
Thanks